# Javascript putting a if statement inside append(' ')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alrighty so below I have this script doing exactly what I want;
I'm using it to add background fadeIn/fadeOut using jquery for my navigation bar.

With my design I have a separator image at the end of each li in a ul for my nav bar; to add that in I'm putting the span in with class "sep" which contains my css to add the separator image as a background in the proper location.

Now my problem is that I have the separator being a background image aligned right so it occurs at the right of each nav item (see below for a text-based example of its structure) and I wish the final item of the navigation to not have the separator.

Current Example Structure:
( Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | )

What I want it to be:
( Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 )

Now to do this inside the javascript I would somehow need to eliminate the entire `"<span class="sep"></span>"` or just the `"class="sep""` ONLY on my last li nav item (its ID is #n7)

So I'm assuming a general way to do it would be to add a if statement that if the current li ID is NOT #n7 (my li ID's go from #n1 to #n7, #n7 being the final) then it puts in `"<span class="sep"></span>"` so if it was #n7 it would not include it

Any help would be great, thanks.

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 //Append a div with hover class to all the LI
 $('#nav li').append('<div class="hover"><span class="sep"></span></div>');



 $('#nav li').hover(

  //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
  function() {

   $(this).children('div').fadeIn('1000'); 

  }, 

  //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
  function() {

   $(this).children('div').fadeOut('1000'); 

 }).click (function () {

  //Add selected class if user clicked on it
  $(this).addClass('selected');

 });

});
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you can place a separator after list items just with CSS, no need to write Javascript for it.

Comment: It's because it's for a jquery fadein/fadeout background hover effect; it's not just a simple css edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:last-child` pseudo-class to select the last child and `:not()` to select all but that. Also `>` to not go down multiple levels but only look at immediate children.

```
$('#nav > li:not(:last-child)').append('<div class="hover"><span class="sep"></span></div>');
$('#nav > li:last-child').append('<div class="hover"></div>');
```

This is a standard CSS selector; in jQuery it will always work but as a CSS selector it would not work in any current release of IE.

Comment: I wish I understood why this was voted down. And why Jacob's messier solution was voted up.

Comment: Was not me, this does seem to work however with the same result as Karim's (see my comment there for the issue)

Comment: @Nto: I updated it shortly after writing it to add in the last child `<div class="hover"></div>` case.

Comment: Very good, didn't see that till now, works like a charm :) Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I used `:last-child` because it's a valid CSS selector and that's what I work with more; jQuery's `:last` is not in CSS but would work just as well. If you had a non-flat structure for it, you'd need to use `:last` rather than `:last-child`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#nav li').each(function() {
   var append_separator = (this != $('#nav li:last')[0]);
   $(this).append('<div class="hover">' + ((append_separator) ? '<span class="sep"></span>' : '') + '</div>')
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ayTn/)

Comment: Good job actually reading his entire question and not coupling your code to the number of li's.

Comment: Am I only replacing the $('#nav li').append('<div class="hover"><span class="sep"></span></div>');  with this? if so, I tried and it seems to break the entire thing...